# Crystal reports in visual studio 2012: smooth line chart

Tags: visual-studio, charts, crystal-reports, linechart

I'm creating reports using Visual Studio 2012, .NET C# and Crystal Reports. Several of the reports is containing line charts. So my question is; is it possible to make the lines in the chart smooth?

I've found a library that does exactly what I want here http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/product_info.php (scroll down and see "Smooth rendering"), but it is too expensive.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?